# Zend Error String

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, zend-form

I have a code here that calles my Errors in group perfectly, but i wanted to add something.

```
$this->setDecorators(array(
            'FormErrors',
            'FormElements',
        array('HtmlTag',array('tag' => 'dl','class' => 'zend_form')),
            'Form'
           ));
```

everytime this error gets called.
           I want to just add a text above the dl or below it..thats says

"ARLET ALERT ERROR ERROR"
just one simple string everytime Zend Errors get called

Any ideas?

Comment: i want it to display a common string above the form eveytime there is an error..i'm not talking about the individual element error messages.

want it to say above: "HEY HEY BELOW ARE ERRORS" as one single string

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom decorator.

```
App_Form_Decorator_AdditionalError
    extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract
{
    protected $_options = array(
        'additionalError' => 'ERROR'
    );

    public function render( $content )
    {
        $element = $this->getElement();
        if( $element->isErrors() )
        {
            $element->addError( $this->getOption( 'additionalError' ) );
        }

        return $content;
    }
}
```

But this would only push an additional error to the stack of errors. You could get more fancy by actually prepending or appending the error to the `$content` in stead of simply adding it with `addError()`. (And perhaps extend the `HtmlTag` decorator in stead of the `Abstract` decorator). But I'm to lazy to make complete example of that right now. Sorry. Maybe I'll get back to this tomorrow. Hope this helps/inspires you nonetheless.

BTW; usage of the above would be:

```
$this->setDecorators(array(
            array(
                'AdditionalError',
                array( 'additionalError' => 'Some additional error message' )
            )
            'FormErrors',
            // etc.
```

**Edit:**
Alright, so I had a good nights sleep, and here is a better suggestion. It extends `Desciption` to take advantage of already defined options, like `tag`, `escape` etc. It's even translatable (yay!! :) ). And this one adds a `setError` option and overrides the `render` method. <strike>It is untested though, so you might get some bugs, and/or syntax errors.</strike>

```
class App_Form_Decorator_AdditionalError
    extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Description
{
    protected $_error = 'error';

    public function setError( $error )
    {
        $this->_error = (string) $error;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getError()
    {
        if( null !== ( $error = $this->getOption( 'error' ) ) )
        {
            $this->setError( $error );
            $this->removeOption( 'error' );
        }

        return $this->_error;
    }

    public function render( $content )
    {
        $element = $this->getElement();
        $view    = $element->getView();
        if( !$element->isErrors() || null === $view )
        {
            return $content;
        }

        $error = $this->getError();
        $error = trim( $error );

        if( !empty( $error ) && ( null !== ( $translator = $element->getTranslator() ) ) )
        {
            $error = $translator->translate( $error );
        }

        if( empty( $error ) )
        {
            return $content;
        }

        $separator = $this->getSeparator();
        $placement = $this->getPlacement();
        $tag       = $this->getTag();
        $class     = $this->getClass();
        $escape    = $this->getEscape();

        $options   = $this->getOptions();

        if( $escape )
        {
            $error = $view->escape( $error );
        }

        if( !empty( $tag ) )
        {
            require_once 'Zend/Form/Decorator/HtmlTag.php';
            $options[ 'tag' ] = $tag;
            $decorator = new Zend_Form_Decorator_HtmlTag( $options );
            $error = $decorator->render( $error );
        }

        switch( $placement )
        {
            case self::PREPEND:
                return $error . $separator . $content;
            case self::APPEND:
            default:
                return $content . $separator . $error;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public function init()
{
    $this->addPrefixPath( 'App_Form', 'App/Form' ); // or any other namespace you will use
    $this->setDecorators( array(
        'FormErrors',
        'FormElements',
        array(
            'AdditionalError',
            array( 'error' => 'You messed up! :)', 'placement' => 'prepend', 'tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'additional-error' )
        ),
        array(
            'HtmlTag',
            array( 'tag' => 'dl', 'class' => 'zend_form' )
        ),
        'Form'
    ) );
}
```

**Edit 2:**
I've tested it now, and removed syntax errors and bugs. Seems to be working as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have used the [Errors decorator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html#zend.form.standardDecorators.errors) but applied to the form itself (rather than the typical use on a form *element*).

**In the form:**

```
$this->setDecorators(
    array(
        'FormElements',
        // whatever other wrapping you need
        // ...
        'Form',
        array('Errors', array('placement' => 'prepend')),

    )
);
```

**In the controller:**

```
public function someAction()
{
    $form = new My_Form();
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {
            // Perform processing on the submitted data
        } else {
            $form->setErrors(array('Note errors below'));
        }
    }
    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

**In the view**

```
<?= $this->form ?>
```

One could compellingly argue that the controller should not be specifying error message text. In this sense, a custom decorator - as suggested by @fireeyedboy - that detects the mere presence of an error in any of the form elements and displays a fixed (or a constructor-specified) error message is probably the cleaner solution. But the approach above has worked for me as a quick-though-slightly-dirty solution.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want your string to be appended to all errors in ZF, you can use CSS2 [:before](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/beforeafter.html) pseudoselector with `content` property. Just target ZF's errors element, which AFAIR is `ul.errors`:

```
ul.errors:before {
    content: 'Look, there are errors below!';
}
```

You can also target some errors, if you pass correct option to decorator and refer to them by class or id.